# Solving IVP related to Dependence on Initial Conditions and Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm asked to solve the initial value problem $$\dot{x}=f(x)\\x(0)=y$$ for $f(x)=(-x_1, -x_2+x_1^2, x_3+x_1^2)^T$. 
I think I need to put it in the form x(t)=Ax, but the $x_1^2$ terms are throwing me off..

I can't find a problem like this in the section nor the previous chapters.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

First solve
$$
\dot x_1=-x_1
$$
Then insert the solution into
$$
\dot x_2=-x_2+x_1^2\\
\dot x_3=x_3+x_1^2
$$
and solve both separately.

Comment: I've tried this, but $x_1=e^{c-t}$. Since $x(0)=y$, does that imply $y=e^c}\Rightarrow c=\ln{y}$? If so, how does $\dot{x_2}$ become a separable equation like $x_1$?

Comment: Correction: $y=e^c\Rightarrow c=\ln{y}$, and $\dot{x_1}$

Comment: $x_1=y_1e^{-t}$ and then insert $\dot x_2=-x_2+y_1^2e^{-2t}$, $x_2(0)=y_2$.